# how to create user in zuora api using dotnet framework

Tags: .net, hmac, zuora

i need to create users in zuora using dotnet framework 4.8.
But I'm having trouble porting the code from java to c#

here is the java implementation https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/Zephr/Developer_Documentation/HMAC_Request_Signing_and_Key_Pairs

```
package io.blaize.api.utilities.security;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Objects;

import io.blaize.api.exception.HmacException;

public class HmacSigner {

    public static final String TWO_DIGIT_HEX_FORMAT = "%1$02x";
    private final String algorithm;

    public HmacSigner(String algorithm) 
    {
        if ("SHA256".equals(algorithm)) {
          this.algorithm = "SHA-256";
        } else {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
      }
    }

   public String signRequest(String secretKey, String body, String path, String query, String method,
                                String timestamp, String nonce) throws HmacException {

    Objects.requireNonNull(secretKey);
    Objects.requireNonNull(body);
    Objects.requireNonNull(path);
    Objects.requireNonNull(query);
    Objects.requireNonNull(method);
    Objects.requireNonNull(timestamp);
    Objects.requireNonNull(nonce);

    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        messageDigest.update(secretKey.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(body.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(path.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(query.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(method.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(timestamp.getBytes());
        messageDigest.update(nonce.getBytes());

        byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest();
        StringBuffer hash = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte digestByte : digest) {
            Integer unsignedInteger = new Integer(Byte.toUnsignedInt(digestByte));
            hash.append(String.format(TWO_DIGIT_HEX_FORMAT, unsignedInteger));
        }
        return hash.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new HmacException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

code for create user:

```
String protocol = "http";
String host = "admin.test.blaize.io";
String path = "/v3/users";
String method = "POST";
String body = "{\"identifiers\": { \"email_address\": \"test@test.com\" }, \"validators\": { \"password\": \"sup3rsecre!10t\" }}";

String accessKey = "xyz";
String secretKey = loadSecretKeySecurely(accessKey);

String timestamp = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String query = "";
String hash = new HmacSigner("SHA-256").
    signRequest(secretKey, body, path, query, method, timestamp, nonce);

String authorizationHeaderValue = "ZEPHR-HMAC-SHA256 "
    + accessKey + ":" + timestamp + ":" + nonce + ":" + hash;

// This is a standard library implementation for illustration only
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(protocol + "://" + host + path + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod(method);
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
outputStream.writeBytes(body);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();

int status = connection.getResponseCode();
if (status >= 200 && status < 400) {
    System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
} else {
System.err.println(status);
```

}

Below is the code in C# :

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
namespace HMACClient
{
     public class HMACDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
      // First obtained the APP ID and API Key from the server
      // The APIKey MUST be stored securely in db or in the App.Config
      private string APPId = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
      private string APIKey = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string requestContentBase64String = string.Empty;
        //Get the Request URI
        string requestUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToLower());
        //Get the Request HTTP Method type
        string requestHttpMethod = request.Method.Method;
        //Calculate UNIX time
        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
        string requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        //Create the random nonce for each request
        string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        //Checking if the request contains body, usually will be null wiht HTTP GET and DELETE
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            // Hashing the request body, so any change in request body will result a different hash
            // we will achieve message integrity
            byte[] content = await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] requestContentHash = md5.ComputeHash(content);
            requestContentBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(requestContentHash);
        }
        //Creating the raw signature string by combinging
        //APPId, request Http Method, request Uri, request TimeStamp, nonce, request Content Base64 String
        string signatureRawData = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", APPId, requestHttpMethod, requestUri, requestTimeStamp, nonce, requestContentBase64String);
        //Converting the APIKey into byte array
        var secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(APIKey);
        //Converting the signatureRawData into byte array
        byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureRawData);
        //Generate the hmac signature and set it in the Authorization header
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyByteArray))
        {
            byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
            string requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
            //Setting the values in the Authorization header using custom scheme (hmacauth)
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("hmacauth", string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", APPId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp));
        }
        response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

}

```
private async void createUser()
{
 Console.WriteLine("Calling the back-end API");
 string apiBaseAddress = "https://mybusiness.api.zephr.com/";
 HMACDelegatingHandler customDelegatingHandler = new HMACDelegatingHandler();
 HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(customDelegatingHandler);

string body = "{\"identifiers\": {\"email_address\": \"joe.blow@company.com\"},\"attributes\": {\"first_name\": \"Joe\",\"surname\": \"Blow\"},\"foreign_keys\" : {\"other_id\" : \"0030C00000Xu1LYQAZ\"}}";

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiBaseAddress + "v3/users", new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Status: {0}, Reason {1}. Press ENTER to exit", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to call the API. HTTP Status: {0}, Reason {1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
 }
}
```

but get error in this line, input string is not valid base64:

```
var secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(APIKey);
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? `xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is indeed not a valid Base64! Apart from that, the question lacks focus.

Comment: I cannot writer secret and appKey over internet. Of course in the real application are valid keys. It's unclair how to edit the code to avoid the exception

Comment: *...I cannot writer secret and appKey over internet...* Sure, and you should not post productive test data, but please test data of the same format and encoding. It's hard to know what are conscious and what are unconscious made mistakes! In any case, the error message indicates that your *real* `APIKey` is not a valid Base64 string (if it triggers this message). I would suggest you take a closer look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, if anyone needs to create a user in zuora this the c# code:

HmacSigner implementation

```
public class HmacSigner
{
    public const string TWO_DIGIT_HEX_FORMAT = "{0:x2}";

    public string SignRequest(string secretKey, string body, string path, string query, string method,
                                string timestamp, string nonce)
    {
        if (secretKey == null || body == null || path == null || query == null || method == null || timestamp == null || nonce == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("All input parameters must not be null");
        }

        try
        {
            using (var messageDigest = SHA256.Create())
            {
                byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
                byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path);
                byte[] queryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query);
                byte[] methodBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(method);
                byte[] timestampBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timestamp);
                byte[] nonceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce);

                messageDigest.TransformBlock(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.Length, keyBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformBlock(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length, bodyBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformBlock(queryBytes, 0, queryBytes.Length, queryBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformBlock(methodBytes, 0, methodBytes.Length, methodBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformBlock(timestampBytes, 0, timestampBytes.Length, timestampBytes, 0);
                messageDigest.TransformFinalBlock(nonceBytes, 0, nonceBytes.Length);

                byte[] digest = messageDigest.Hash;
                StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte digestByte in digest)
                {
                    hash.AppendFormat(TWO_DIGIT_HEX_FORMAT, digestByte);
                }
                return hash.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred while generating HMAC", e);
        }
    }
}
```

create user code:

```
void CreateUser()
{
    string protocol = "https";
    string host = "xxx.api.zephr.com";
    string path = "/v3/users";
    string method = "POST";
    string body = "{\"identifiers\": { \"email_address\": \"joe.blow@company.com\" }, \"validators\": { \"password\": \"sup3rsecre!10t\" }}";

    string accessKey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string secretKey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    string timestamp = Math.Round((DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds, 0).ToString();
    string nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string query = "";
    string hash = new HmacSigner().SignRequest(secretKey, body, path, query, method, timestamp, nonce);

    string authorizationHeaderValue = "ZEPHR-HMAC-SHA256 " + accessKey + ":" + timestamp + ":" + nonce + ":" + hash;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(protocol + "://" + host + path + "?" + query);
    request.Method = method;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    var postBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(postBody, 0, postBody.Length);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    int status = (int)response.StatusCode;
    Console.WriteLine(status);
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
        }
}
```